# How to use DATABSE_URL in Play 2.0 (Scala) for local connection to PostgreSQL 9.1 & Heroku?

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

I have developed a first web application using a local PostgreSQL 9.1 on OSX (Lion 10.7.4) using Play! Framework 2.0.3. I started with my database connection defined in conf/application.conf (relative to application's directory) with

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/fotoplay"
db.default.user=foo
db.default.password=bar
```

(username and password have been changed before posting) This works for  writing and testing.  I now want to deploy to Heroku.  I have set up the Procfile (in application's directory) with a single line:

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS}  
-DapplyEvolutions.default=false 
-Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver 
-Ddb.default.url=$DATABASE_URL
```

I have exported DATABASE_URL in .bash_profile so that I can echo $DATABASE_URL at the system command line and get

```
postgres://foo:bar@localhost/photoplay
```

At Heroku, I have set up an instance of postgresql.  I'm not sure on how to write a database evolution to populate heroku, so I turned that off evolutions and populated my database manually.  My current evolutions build tables and populate them with some initial data from some csv files, so I would need to place the csv files somewhere accessible to heroku.  At least for a first pass, I don't want to tackle this issue just yet.  But as a result of the manual steps, I have a populated database on Heroku.

With this configuration, my application runs correctly locally.  However, I am not using DATABASE_URL, which seems wrong.  I pushed this to HEROKU and is is not able to connect to the database.  The error is:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "foo"
```

If I remove the username & password, I break my local configuration.  I should be able to use DATABASE_URL 'instead of' the older syntax, but I don't quite know how to do that.  I don't think that I can figure this out experimentally (wandering high dimensional spaces is hopeless, and there are several possible configuration settings that might be involved & are subject to typos).  Any guidance on how I should set up application.conf would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Worth a try: in your `application.conf` file, change your `db.default.url` parameter in order to include the username & password in the URL, and remove the `db.default.user` and `db.default.password` parameters:

```
db.default.url="postgres://foo:bar@localhost/fotoplay"
```

Comment: This is right.  Your `db.default.user` and `db.default.password` config params are still getting picked up.  You can just use the `postgres://username@password@hostname/dbname` syntax for local and on Heroku.  In which case the `db.default.user` and `db.default.password` params are no longer needed.

Comment: The correct format for db.default.password is db.default.url="postgres://foo:bar@localhost/fotoplay'

Comment: I had an extra 'ql' and I didn't need the leading 'jdbc'.  But once I got that straight, I could drop the user and password and all working.  This worked both locally and on heroku.  So thank you both for the guidance.  I do wish I knew how to just reference a shell variable in the Play configuration so my local passwords were not sitting in the source at Heroku.

Comment: @BobFolkerts: +1: When I use jdbc:postgresql://ac@ac:localhost/ac, it tells me "Unknown host ac@ac:localhost". But when I use the 'postgres:' syntax, it works.